# ¿Cómo Trabajar con Variables Mas Largas que las de 64BITS?

Tags: vb.net

Necesitaría hacer cálculos mas largos de los que hace las variables `Double` de VB.NET por lo que pienso que podría hacer un nuevo tipo de variables que ocuparán 128 bits en vez de 64bits de las `double` y no se por donde hacerlo, ¿alguien tiene consejos que me puedan servir para este tipo de operaciones largas  con números mas grandes de las variables `Double`?

No tengo código de ejemplo ya que no se crear tipos nuevos de datos,

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: [`Decimal`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/decimal-data-type) tiene 128 bits...

Comment: Pero son 64 arriba y 64 abajo ( desde 0 )

Comment: yo necesito por lo menos 128 arriba se me queda a la mitad

Comment: y Molaria hasta de 256 o mas dependiendo de lo que requieras...

Comment: Pues en realidad, yo no le veo mucho sentido la verdad. Básicamente, su rendimiento va a ser muy pobre, y si realmente necesitas gestionar numeros tan extensos, probablemente debas buscar alternativas a .Net. De todas maneras, simplemente mira [la implementacion de Decimal](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs) y ahi tienes como hacer un tipo acorde a tus necesidades.

Comment: No es exactamente lo que preguntas pero en Net 4.0+ dispones de [BigInteger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), sino, hay una implementación de de un `UInt128`  [aquí](https://github.com/ricksladkey/dirichlet-numerics)

Comment: Es muy largo de explicar pero en fin, es cuestión de crear funciones hasta llegar a eso, hacer cálculos Mayores a 64 BITS de Memoria... Mi Proyecto Pol Power Calculator es la Prueba de ello y el código ocupa 4000 líneas...

Comment: Se utilizan Strings en vez de Integers o ULongs Para Aberiguar el Número Junto a Más de 30 Funciones , Ocupa Mucho Espacio el como se hace así que voy a obiar este comentario...

Comment: Tampoco Sirve Doblar el Tamaño de la Variable ULongs a BigIntegers, Con Strings y Las Funciones Desarrolladas Que he Hecho, el Limite de Dígitos es de Largadas de Integers...